# If statement is not working with char in C

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, printf, scanf

I've been trying to make this if work I've tried to put scanf in every way possible and that was not the problem because it picks it up the "+" is stored as I see it on the printf below.
Can anyone figure out why not?
Thanks

```c
float number1;
float number2;
float total;
char operator[1];
printf("Welcome to the calculator\n");
while(3>2)
{
    printf("Pick a number\n");
    scanf("%f", &number1);
    
    printf("Que quieres hacer?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &operator);
    printf("You wrote %s\n", operator);
    
    if(operator =='+')
    {
        printf("This works!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `if` is broken. Do you get the same result if you change `operator` to, say, `op`?

Comment: @Explosivo30 Show how the variable operator is defined.

Comment: This code can't be compiled. The biggest problem, to my mind, is that `operator` is undefined.

Comment: @TimRandall The biggest problem is that there's no function definition. We need a [mre].

Comment: @KeithThompson it's a subjective matter. Personally, I can work with isolated scraps of code fairly easily. I can't work with undefined variables.  It forces one to either make assumptions or try to handle multiple possibilities, neither of which makes for a great answer

Comment: I posted an incorrect answer based on my own misreading of the `scanf` call. That was entirely my fault, and I've deleted the answer. You've added more context to the code in your question, but it's not a [mre]. Someone should be able to copy-and-paste the code from your question and compile and run it. That means you need a definition of `main` and the required `#include <stdio.h>`. And you need to compile your program with warning enabled, and include any warning or error messages in your question. When I expand your code to a complete program and compile it, I get two diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet

```
    scanf(" %c", &operator);
    printf("You wrote %s\n", operator);
    
    if(operator =='+')
    {
        printf("This works!");
    }
```

is incorrect independent on how the variable `operator` is declared.

If the variable `operator` is declared like

```
char operator;
```

then this statement

```
printf("You wrote %s\n", operator);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

In this case you need to write

```
printf("You wrote %c\n", operator);
```

If the variable `operator` is declared as a character array as for example

```
char operator[N];
```

where `N` is some value then at least this statement

```
if(operator =='+')
```

does not make a sense and the condition will always evaluate to false.

Pay attention to that instead of this condition in the while loop

```
while(3>2)
```

it would be much simpler and readable just to write

```
while ( 1 )
```

Comment: And of `operator` is defined as `char *operator;` then the snippet is wrong at least one, and probably two other ways.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is not defined as `char *` only decays to `char *`

Comment: Thanks, I declared the char as char operator[1]

Comment: @Explosivo30 I thought so.:)